# Dot Product In purrr

Tags: r, purrr

How would I calculate the dot product in `purrr`? As a reprex, here is a simple example.

#### Data generation

```
 #fake data 
 X <- as_tibble(list(a = rnorm(10,0,1), 
        b = rnorm(10,10,1), 
        c = rnorm(10,100,1)))
 z <- c(1,0,1) 

 #make tibble matrix
 X_matrix <- X %>% as.matrix()
 X_matrix
                a         b         c
 [1,]  0.01182775  9.032966 100.95322
 [2,]  0.85718250 10.015310 102.30181
 [3,] -0.06742915 10.535482 100.21764
 [4,] -0.18236798  9.052234  99.37345
 [5,] -0.32151084 10.329401  98.81186
 [6,]  2.94303948  9.994800  99.93874
 [7,]  0.03299169  9.079023  99.73501
 [8,]  0.06518171  8.841637  99.91130
 [9,] -0.71944580 10.281631 100.32533
[10,]  1.49983359 10.776108  99.35903
```

#### Calculate dot product

The dot product is `sum(a*z[1] + b*z[2] + c*z[3])`

```
 X_matrix %*% z
           [,1]
 [1,] 100.96505
 [2,] 103.15900
 [3,] 100.15021
 [4,]  99.19108
 [5,]  98.49035
 [6,] 102.88178
 [7,]  99.76800
 [8,]  99.97648
 [9,]  99.60588
[10,] 100.85886
```

Ideally, I would like to add the dot product as a column to `X`

Comment: `X %>% dplyr::mutate(foo = as.matrix(.) %*% z)` ?

Comment: @Aurèle thanks, I can't believe it was that simple. For some reason I was thinking of needing a dot product function.